# Images are not displaying

Tags: magento-1.7, adminhtml, php-5.4

I am new to Magento.

I have create one dummy page in Magento, when I display this page images are not showing.

But this code works in an .html file. Could you tell me where I went wrong?

```
public function indexAction()
    {
        echo '<html lang="en">';
        echo '<head>';
        echo '<title>Simplest jQuery Slideshow</title>';
        echo '<style type="text/css">
        .body
        {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        .fadein
        {
            position: relative;
            height: 332px;
            width: 500px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background: url("slideshow-bg.png") repeat-x scroll left top transparent;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        .fadein img
        {
            position: absolute;
            left: 10px;
            top: 10px;
        }
         </style>';
        echo '<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo ' $(function () {';
        echo '$(\'.fadein img:gt(0)\').hide();';
        echo 'setInterval(function () { $(\'.fadein :first-child\').fadeOut().next(\'img\').fadeIn().end().appendTo(\'.fadein\'); }, 3000);
        });';
        echo '</script>';
        echo '</head>
        <body>
        <div class="fadein">';
        echo '<img src="C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/skin/frontend/test/default/images/media/1.jpg" >
        <img src="C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/skin/frontend/test/default/images/media/2.jpg" >
        <img src="C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/skin/frontend/test/default/images/media/3.jpg" >
        <img src="C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/skin/frontend/test/default/images/media/4.jpg" >
        <img src="C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/skin/frontend/test/default/images/media/5.jpg" >
         </div>
        </body>
        </html>';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd advice you to move your HTML to a PHTML file using the layout XML. [This blogpost](http://magento4u.wordpress.com/2009/06/08/create-new-module-helloworld-in-magento/) should help you along with that.

For displaying images located in the skin folder please use `$this->getSkinUrl('images/imagename.jpg');`. This will dynamically set the right path.

Answer (score 1):

**Your actual problem:**

I doubt that your image path should be a fully-qualified path on-disk. You image path should be relative to your domain.

**A better way:**

You should consider this being a CMS page. You can edit all of the source *and* upload images - it'll resolve the image path for you.

Additionally, as Sander points out, almost all of the content you're `echo`-ing should be in a template include (phtml) file.  Echoing content in the manner you're doing is bound to be wrought with problems.

**Off topic / Don't do this:**

If you do insist on setting body content directly from a controller, at least do it with PHP heredoc and `setBody`:

```
    public function indexAction()
    {

$html = <<<HTML

    <html>
    <head>
        <title>My Sweet Stand-alone page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>I AM TEH AWSUM!</h1>
    </body>
    </html>


HTML;


    $this->getResponse()->setBody($html);

    }
```

Beware, the lack of indentation in the heredoc syntax is meaningful.

**Even though I know you probably will - please, please, please, don't do this.**

---

Read more about heredoc over here, doc:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc